# How to use "exit" to stop an Alexa skill or handle unrecognized utterances?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am playing around with the Alexa SDK and I came across a strange behavior. I am trying to implement all possible ways a user could end a session. The problem I have is that the word "exit" returns Alexa saying "There was a problem..." and quits the skill immediately. All other words like "stop" or "cancel" work fine and return a goodbye message.

Here is how I implement the handlers:

```
'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
    this.emit('SessionEndRequest');
},
'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
    this.emit('SessionEndRequest');
},
'SessionEndRequest': function() {
    const speech_output = 'Goodbye and take care!'

    this.emit(':tell', speech_output);
},
```

As you can see to keep this as simple as possible right now I redirect the *StopIntent* and *CancelIntent* to the *SessionEndRequest* which returns a goodbye message. This works great, except for "exit" which is not recognized.

Is there a way to implement this? I tried to use a custom intent (called ExitIntent) with the utterance "exit" plus a bunch of other ones like "see ya", "until next time" and all work well except for the "exit" utterance.

Or is there a way to handle an unrecognized utterance - ie. return the *HelpIntent*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle an unrecognized utterance, simply create an `Unhandled` request.

```
'Unhandled': function () {
     const speech_output = 'Goodbye and take care!'
     this.emit(':tell', speech_output);
}
```

This should solve your issue of the 'exit' not working.

Comment: Do I have to create an 'Unhandled' intent as well or is this a sdk included handler? And what is the difference between this.emit((':tell', someText...) and this.response.speak('someText...)

Comment: No, you don't need to create another Intent. 'Unhandled' is a built in handler. With the second question, doing this.response.speak is a way to build response first using responseBuilder and then emit instead of emitting the response directly. There is no difference really. Both do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Simple fix, add "exit" as an utterance to the AMAZON.StopIntent